# Windows caption font changing c++ specific application

Tags: c++, window

I have figured out how to change the menu font...I have been experimenting with

```
NONCLIENTMETRICS nm;
nm.cbSize = sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS);
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, nm.cbSize, &nm, 0);
```

which compiles...but if I want to set the font for the application window, then what should I do, use SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the SPI stuff here? Those are for system-wide settings, which may not be your intent.

Comment: Yes, you use `SPI_SETNONCLIENTMETRICS` to *set* the non-client metrics. But keep in mind that these are *global* settings (the same ones you change in the Personalization control panel), not unique to your application. If you want to change the *global* menu font, then you modify the `lfMenuFont` member of the `NONCLIENTMETRICS` structure. If you want to change the caption font (which displays the title of your application in the window frame), then you modify `lfCaptionFont`. But you *probably* don't want to mess with either of these. James has your answer for an individual window.